# Python, how can I change in-place a sub array?

Tags: python, list, in-place, sub-array

For example, I have a function

```
def foo(a):
    a[0],a[1] = a[1], a[0]
```

And

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

The `foo(a)` changes value of `a` in-place but `foo(a[:1])` does not.
Please help to let me know how can I make `foo(a[:1])` change value of `a` in-place

Comment: `list` slicing *creates new list objects*. The `list` you pass in `foo(a[:1])` **does change in place**. However, you lose all references to that list so it is immediately garbage collected when the function terminates and it's reference count goes to 0. Note, you are working with *lists* not arrays.

Comment: Thanks, so the right question should be how to make slicing with references to the same object? Anyway, list in python is a dynamic array. I want to do it recursively by passing a segment of the current list, but doing it does not change anything in the original list.

Comment: Again **list slicing always returns a new list**. You cannot slice a list without creating a new list. You can implement your own slicing function, create a wrapper class that does this, or just pass around indices. I mention that about `list` objects because Python *does* have arrays, but `list` are not them. Generally, in the context of Python, "array" means specifically `numpy.ndarray` objects, or even `array.array` objects. And note, `numpy.ndarray` objects produce *views* of the original array, so this would have worked if you were actually using arrays!

Comment: Thanks, sorry I made some confusion. I was hoping that there is a way to pass the reference with slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, when you slice a list it creates a new copy, which is what you are modifying in-place instead. Consider either:

```
def foo(a):
    a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]
    return a

a = [1,2,3]
a[1:] = foo(a[1:])
```

or

```
def foo(a, i=0):
    a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]
```

where `i` is your slice index.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with an index.

```
def foo(a, n):
    a[n],a[n+1] = a[n+1], a[n]
```

Comment: I want to do it recursively, so the next list is a segment of the current list.